# Mongodb aggregation project $filter $ne failing in spring boot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, filter, mongodb-query, projection

I have the following mongodb aggregation :

```
[{$project: {
         studentID : "$student.id",
         bookId:{$cond: {
           if: { $eq: [ "$type", "sourceName" ] },
           then: "$from.id",
           else: ""
                }
             }
          }}, 
   {$group: {
             _id: '$studentID',
             bookId :{"$push": "$bookId"}
          }}, 

   {$project: {
            bookId :{
                 $filter:{
                     input:"$bookId",
                     as:"testBookID",
  cond:{$ne: ["$$testBookID",""]}
            }
         }
        }}]
```

As there is chance of bookId being null in some cases, at the end of group, getting an array having both null and valid values like [,,,,bk001,,]
Doing the last project to filter out the value/values which are not null.
The above aggregation is running fine in compass and returning correct value but when trying to implement in Java Spring Boot getting this exception :
"$java" : org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.MatchOperation@401b8515

Spring boot code :

```
Cond bookIdcond = ConditionalOperators.when(Criteria.where("type").is("sourceName"))
            .thenValueOf("from.id").otherwise("");
ProjectionOperation projectOperation1 = Aggregation.project().and(bookIdcond).as("bookId");
GroupOperation groupOperation = Aggregation.group("studentID").push("bookId").as("bookId");
ProjectionOperation projectOperation2 = Aggregation.project()             
      .and(filter("bookId").as("testBookID").by(valueOf("testBookID").notEqualTo(""))).as("bookId");
```

Getting the error at last projection.
The exception getting while executing the last projection line :
**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AggregationField name must not be null or empty!**
Please help with the code.

Comment: You may want to use _addFields_ stage instead of projection (the first one). _project_ and _addFields_ have different purposes.